# Is it possible to trim a string in an .htaccess RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small set of rules in an .htaccess file within a directory on my Apache webserver. The file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /tools

FallbackResource /tools/view.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\ \+_-]+)/$ view.php?sid=$1 [NS,L]
```

All this does is rewrites the url to something clean like `example.com/tools/sid/` rather than `example.com/tools/view.php?sid=xxx`

The view.php controller trims the string on the backend to 20 characters so that you can't simply input any string. It works well however I've noticed that one can input anything into the URL and it will process it correctly, but the URL will display in the browser with the full string of garbage. As an example, a (*possibly malicious*) user could enter:

```
https://example.com/tools/ABC123DEF456GHI789JKfda;/adh?afd32*ad
```

And it will process correctly, but display as above.

Is it possible to trim the string to display only the first 20 characters of the `sid` above within this RewriteRule?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\ \+_-]+)/$ view.php?sid=$1 [NS,L]
```

Comment: If you want to change what the browser address bar shows, then you will need an external redirect.

Comment: _"a (possibly malicious) user could enter:"_ - then why redirect them in the first place? There is no need to treat malicious users "nicely" - I would give a 404 or 403 response, and done.

Comment: Agreed with  @CBroe, it would make more sense to block URIs with more than 20 chars rather than redirecting (though that is also possible)

Comment: Really good point, not sure why I didn’t think about that. That’s the easiest thing to do indeed. Thank you!